# Liferay HotDeploy error registering portlets

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I'm setting up Liferay app.

Liferay version 6.2
Tomcat version 7.0.62
Java version 1.8.0_271 (liferay and tomcat don't use higer version of Java) I also tried versions 1.7.0_80, 1.8.202, 1.8.211, 1.8.241

My environment variables:

1. JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
2. JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\jre

Step to reproduce:

1. Install JDK
2. Write environment variables
3. Download liferay 6.2
4. Open file portal-setup-wizard and write string: setup.wizard.enabled=true
5. Start tomcat
6. Open localhost:8080
7. Registration on portal
8. Then I try to deploy .war file by pasting this in /deploy folder
9. Then I get the error:

   05:20:07,194 INFO  [localhost-startStop-2][PortletHotDeployListener:344] Registering portlets for Test-portlet
   05:20:07,432 ERROR [localhost-startStop-2][HotDeployImpl:233] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException:
   Error registering portlets for Test-portlet com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException:
   Error registering portlets for Test-portletTest-portlet at         com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:46)
10. There is the feauture: only one portlet has this error, other portlets installed successfully. **BUT** this wrong portlet file installed successfully at my collegues...

What's wrong? Help please

Comment: From your tags, we know [tag:liferay-6] - but nothing more: Which _exact_ version? Steps to reproduce? Your setup? Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] to make this question answerable.

Comment: @OlafKock I idited my question. I very sorry for my bad English.

Comment: All of the detailed steps you're giving are for the environment - and then there's some arbitrary custom code that doesn't deploy. What's that code? Are there more entries in the log file? Can you provide that code simplified as a [mcve]? And is there any reason why you're installing a "fresh" copy of a version superceded by 4 more releases? We're at Liferay 7.3 by now